# How to write value for keypath query on NSArray in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wish to write a function which takes a NSArray of Employees. In return it should give list of all Employees whose salary summation exceeds threshold. The array first need to be sorted in joining date ascending order of employee. The class structure looks like:-

```
@interface Employee : NSObject
@property NSString *name;
@property EmployeeMetadata *empMetadata;
@end

@interface EmployeeMetadata : NSObject
@property NSString *salary;
@property NSDate *joiningDate;
@end
```

I have written the code in following manner:-

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                    initWithKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"empMetadata.joiningDate"]
                                    ascending:TRUE];
[employeeArr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];


NSInteger actual;
NSInteger thresholdExceedIndex = -1;
for (Employee *item in employeeArr) {
    actual = actual + [item.empMetadata.salary integerValue];
    if(actual >= totalThresholdSalary) {
        thresholdExceedIndex = [employeeArr indexOfObject:item];
        break;
    }
}

// if exceeded delete employee in FIFO
if(thresholdExceedIndex != -1) {
    [self deleteEmployees:[employeeArr subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, (thresholdExceedIndex + 1))]]
}
```

Can we write this in better way

How can i achieve this using NSArray valueforkeypath query?

Comment: It should be array of dictionary.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy why it should be array of dictionary?

Comment: Pls put in code that you have tried to write, and indicate which part of it is not working.

Comment: You need to sort your Object with sort enumerator and will get final sorted or filter array of object.

Comment: I have added my approach. Please suggest a better approach or anything i can improve on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation of -> **Why you need array of dictionary.**

Your format should be like this

```
(
    {
        "name" = "Balraj"
        "metaData" = "your Data" // Whatever data is as per you set by the class 'EmployeeMetadata'.
    },
    {
        "name" = "tinu"
        "metaData" = "mine Data" 
    }   
)
```

As per your requirement you have to set person `name` and its crossponding `metadata` at the same index. So you have to structure should be like this.

Here in example I just take the string for explanation but in real scenario you have t save object of metaData so that you can access further their crossponding objects like `Salary`  and `joiningData`.

**HOW TO ACCESS OBJECTS**

**Assuming :** you have successfully saved all the records as per above structure.

So to fetch data `DOJ` you have to do something like below:

```
EmployeeMetadata* balrajData = array[0]["metaData"]
NSDate *balrajDOJ = balrajData. joiningDate.
```

Even you can use for loop :

```
NSMuatableArray *arrMutDOJ = [NSMuatableArray new];

for (int i = 0; i< array.count; i++){
  EmployeeMetadata* metaData = array[0]["metaData"]
  NSDate *DOJ = balrajData.joiningDate
  arrMutDOJ.add(DOJ)
}
```

Now in `arrMutDOJ` you have DOJ of all empoyles, now you can sort them in increasing order. (As per your requirement).